# backbone.js - how can i fetch local or server data

Tags: backbone.js

I am very new to backbone.js, to try it out I made a function to append an element using my array. But I don't know how to fetch the same from server or my local path.

I tried with some tutorial but still I couldn't get any good result. Can any one correct my function to fetch the data from local folder or server?

code :

this is my local path: `'..data/data.json'`

```
(function($){ 
  var student = [
    {name:'student1'},
    {name:'student2'},
    {name:'student3'}
  ]

var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    name:'default name'  
  }
});

var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:model  
});

var itemViews = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagname:'li',
  render:function(){
    this.$el.html(this.model.get('name'));
    return this;
  }  
})

var view = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#contacts"),
  initialize:function(){
    this.collection = new collection(student);
    this.render();
  },
  render:function(){
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
      that.renderName(item);
    })
  },
  renderName:function(item){
    var itemView = new itemViews({model:item});
    this.$el.append(itemView.render().el);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Collections have the `url` property which links to the url where the models can be fetched (in a proper JSON format of course).

If you have a RESTful API you can tie them directly to a collection on your backend.

In your case you can modify the collection definition as follows

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model:model,
  url: '..data/data.json' //OR WHATEVER THE URL IS 
});
```

Then when instantiating your collection you have to call the fetch() method to fill in the collection.

```
   myCollection = new collection();
   myCollection.fetch();
```

For more information see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263539/how-to-set-a-collections-url)

Comment: i made the corrections, but i am not getting the out put. but the console show the data.

Comment: When you instantiate the collection you have to fetch the models. I update the post...

Answer (score 4):

Backbone will call GET, POST, DELETE, etc on that same url depending on what needs to be sent or received from the server. So if you are building the REST api, your controller or router should route the appropriate functions to those methods. See below for exact mapping:

```
create → POST   /collection
read → GET   /collection[/id]
update → PUT   /collection/id
delete → DELETE   /collection/id
```

As a side note, if you have no control over the JOSN that is returned from the server, you can format it in any format you like in the parse function.

```
parse: function(response) { return response.itemYouWantAdded; }
```

This would be the case if your server is returning an object within an object, such as twitter feeds.

Or you could simply populate the model from the response manually in the parse function

```
parse: function(response) { var tmpModel = { 
                            item1:response.item1, 
                            item2:response.item2 
                            }; 
return tmpModel;  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can [set a URL for your model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) or for [your collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url). Then when you run [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) it will read your JSON straight into either a single model or a collection of models. So in your case, your collection might look like

```
var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '..data/data.json',
    model: model
});

collection.fetch(); // Could also use collection.reset()
```

You just need to make sure your JSON is formatted properly to match your model's attributes.

Comment: why don't you try adding what you have to a http://jsfiddle.net/ and people can chip in?